# Forced shutdown during bsod

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod, shutdown

I accidentally forced my PC to shutdown by holding onto the power button during a BSOD in windows 10 and ever since, my PC has not been able to boot to the login screen instead it keeps giving the "Inaccessible Boot Device" error.
I have tried all the recovery options but none of which seems to work.

PS I also have Kali Linux installed (and working currently) on the same hard drive.

How exactly can i make my PC boot without loosing any of my files

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How exactly can i make my PC boot without loosing any of my files?

Comment: remove the HDD cable and connect it again. "Inaccessible Boot Device" means windows can't see the drive. also change the SATA mode in BIOS. changing it from IDE to AHCI (versa vice) can also cause this message

Comment: still no good. already tried all that

Comment: The BSOD itself has more to do with your boot problems then your actions after the BSOD happened.

Comment: Ramhound, please what do you suggest i do?

Comment: [Install ntfs-3g with sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g. Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition. **`ntfsfix /dev/hda6`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1) since it doesn't seem a hardware problem (Linux is booting), use clonezilla (http://clonezilla.org/) or similar to make a full disk image of your harddrive onto an external hdd, so you have a backup of your data.

2) If you can't recover your current installation from a win10 recovery disk (Google for: "How to create a Windows 10 recovery disk"), you will need to clean-install win 10 from cd or usb. If your current installation is still "recognizable" by the win 10 installer,  it should give you the option to "keep my personal files".

3) once win10 runs,  recover missing data from the backup.

You might want to do a chkdsk just to be sure there are no bad sectors on the disk causing the initial problem